# How to join two columns with little difference in names

Tags: sql

I have 2 files. one file consists of company names eg: ABC private limited/ABC and other file consists of Company name eg : ABC/ABC Pvt Ltd/ABC something . So if I have to match these 2 columns in order to check if the Company from 1st file exists in other file and get the remaining data from file 2 how do i do that???

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: To be honest, instead of updating the question it would be quicker to search for 'SQL Server fuzzy matching' or 'Postgresql fuzzy matching' to find your answer

Comment: Thanks @JeffUK it was helpful the fuzzy

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.